# Не удаётся запустить программу в Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 не удаётся найти указанный файл

Tags: visual-studio, ассемблер, masm32

Здравствуйте при компиляции кода в Visual Studio выдаёт вот такую ошибку, уже 2-й день сижу не могу решить данную проблему.
С кодом проблем нет[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод программы:

1>\masm32\include\winextra.inc(11052): error A2026: constant expected
1>\masm32\include\winextra.inc(11053): error A2026: constant expected
1>main3.asm(6): fatal error A1000: cannot open file : P:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc

Comment: Как нет проблем? А *\masm32\include\winextra.inc(11052): error A2026: constant expected* - это же и есть проблема с кодом. Дальше - код не скомпилирован, программа не создана, вот и не удается найти указанный файл - его просто нет.

Answer (score -1):

Имя профиля пользователя попробуйте на латинице использовать...

Comment: Проблема, к сожалению, не в этом(

Comment: Мне кажется, что Ваша главная проблема - использование VS. При этом у вас в один клубок смешиваются проблемы программы и проблемы настройки среды разработки. попрбуйте сделать всё из командной строки - вы лучше поймете процессы компиляции и сборки, и, скоре всего, решите всё за один день. А когда программа будет работать - можете вернуться к настройке VS.